# How can I get value from prompt dialog and submit form in Laravel?

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-blade, alpine.js

When a user clicks a submit button, I prevent the event in Alpine.js and open a prompt dialog to capture a card number. That value should be stored in a hidden input value before I fire the submit event for the form. This is my Blade / Alpine.Js code:

```html
<form x-data="{ card: '' }" x-on:submit.prevent="card = prompt('Insert card'); if(card !== null) $el.submit()" method="POST" action="{{ route('member.store', ['identity' => $identity->id]) }}">
    @csrf
    <input type="hidden" x-bind:value="card" name="tessera"/>
    <button type="submit"><img class="object-scale-down h-6 ml-5" src="{{asset('images/card_add.png')}}" title="Aggiungi tessera" alt="Aggiungi tessera"></button>
</form>
```

The problem is the value of the hidden input is always null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when the form is submitted via *submit()*, the hidden input has not yet been updated.
To overcome this we can use the *$nextTick* magic property that executes a certain expression after reactive DOM updates have been made:

```html
<form x-data="{ card: '' }" 
      x-on:submit.prevent="card = prompt('Insert card'); if(card) $nextTick (() => {$el.submit()});" 
      method="POST" 
      action="{{ route('member.store', ['identity' => $identity->id]) }}"
>
    <!-- ..... -->
</form>
```

Here I've tested *card* with a loose comparison to discard empty inputs that result in an empty string.